# How do you throttle (put a limit) your database mail?

Tags: sql-server

I discovered today that we have a really ridiculously powerful SMTP server, when I forgot my where clause and sent out 20,000 emails in 4 seconds.

How do I put a limit on my database mail to only send out a few dozen emails per minute?

Comment: This has to be done in your script logic which invokes database mail.

Comment: You _might_ be able to take advantage of the _queue_ solution as referenced in [Limiting DatabaseMail sending rate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25246644/limiting-databasemail-sending-rate)